# AD677JNZ Raspberry Pi Connection

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, spi, serial

Relatively new to electronics, I would like to connect the [AD677JNZ](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/AD677-3118542.pdf) analog-to-digital (ADC) to a Raspberry Pi 4 to monitor the voltage of a potentiometer. However, I am having issues with the connections of the ADC. The AD677JNZ uses a serial communication. However, the pinout states that there is an SCLK signal, so I am slightly confused since serial communications typically only have a Tx and Rx pin. Based on the pin diagram of the ADC from the data sheet, these are the connections I currently have set up, when I tried running my code the voltage on the potentiometer remained at 0 V, even though I was rotating the potentiometer knob.

My goal with this is to be able to change the potentiometer manually and be able to read the voltage on the wiper using the ADC.

[image: ADC677JNZ Pinout]

1. Pin 1 - + 5V
2. Pin 2 - GPIO11 (SCLK)
3. Pin 3 - GPIO9 MISO
4. Pin 4 - 0 V
5. Pin 5 - +5V
6. Pin 6 - Not connected
7. Pin 7 - Not connected
8. Pin 8 - 0 V
9. Pin 9 - 0 V
10. Pin 10 - Potentiometer Wiper
11. Pin 11 - + 5V
12. Pin 12 - 0 V
13. Pin 13 - + 5V
14. Pin 14 - GPIO11 (SCLK)
15. Pin 15 - + 5V
16. Pin 16 - Not connected

Below is an image of the pin description for this ADC from the data sheet.

[image: Pin Description]

The code I am using:
[image: Reading ADC Values]

Thank you for taking your time to read this. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: At first glance this looks more like SPI than a UART, so you’re on the right track.  You may need connections to SAMPLE and BUSY.  Given that you need 17 clock cycles to complete a conversion (SPI is usually multiples of 8 bits) you might end up bit-banging, I.e. driving CLK high and low while reading DATA as a digital input to read each bit.

Comment: It seems like it would make sense to connect MOSI to sample, I'll have to figure out BUSY though. I'll also need to find ways to avoid bit banging in that case as well.

Comment: Bit-banging isn’t anything to be scared of, it’s not very efficient in compute terms but if reading the ADC is essentially all your doing then it will have minimal impact on performance.  It’s not like the bad old days when we’d be counting up every last CPU cycle on an 8-bit micro.